# SRT (SubRip Text) to JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, algorithm

I'm trying to produce a JSON file from an SRT file. I am using Python to do the task. I have below code, which when writing the output on terminal is showing correct output, but when I am producing one JSON file out of it is showing /n after every line. I don't know why that's happening. Can anyone help over here? If not even producing, then I just want to fetch variables from that SRT file. Like timing or sentence. Let's just suppose there is startTime and endTime for every sentence in SRT. I want to fetch the startTime, can we do it even without producing the output? I am just out of clues here. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code..

```
import sys
import re
import json

regex = r'(?:\d+)\s(\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+) --> (\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)\s+(.+?)(?:\n\n|$)'
offset_seconds = lambda ts: sum(howmany * sec for howmany, sec in zip(map(int, ts.replace(',', ':').split(':')), [60 * 60, 60, 1, 1e-3]))

transcript = [dict(startTime = offset_seconds(startTime), endTime = offset_seconds(endTime), ref = ' '.join(ref.split())) for startTime, endTime, ref in re.findall(regex, open('My_SRT_File.srt').read(), re.DOTALL)]

a=json.dumps(transcript, ensure_ascii = False, indent = 2)

with open('data.json','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(a,f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Output from the produced json file:

"[\n  {\n    "startTime": 30.0,\n    "endTime": 36.0,\n    "ref": "Provided by YTS.LT"\n  },\n  {\n    "startTime": 36.5,\n    "endTime": 42.0,\n    "ref": "Find the official YIFY movies site at https://YTS.LT"\n  },\n  {\n    "startTime": 1830.0,\n    "endTime": 1836.0,\n    "ref": "Downloaded from YTS.LT"\n  },\n  {\n    "startTime": 3630.0,\n    "endTime": 3636.0,\n    "ref": "Download more movies for free from YTS.LT"\n  }\n]"

You will see it is not in correct JSON format and \n's everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting a Python object to a string with `json.dumps` and then writing the string out...but `json.dump` can write your object out directly.

The reason you have the \n and all, is because the json library is treating your string object as a JSON object to write out. You should pass the JSON object (dictionary or list) directly to `json.dump`.

```
import sys
import re
import json

regex = r'(?:\d+)\s(\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+) --> (\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)\s+(.+?)(?:\n\n|$)'
offset_seconds = lambda ts: sum(howmany * sec for howmany, sec in zip(map(int, ts.replace(',', ':').split(':')), [60 * 60, 60, 1, 1e-3]))

transcript = [dict(startTime = offset_seconds(startTime), endTime = offset_seconds(endTime), ref = ' '.join(ref.split())) for startTime, endTime, ref in re.findall(regex, open('My_SRT_File.srt').read(), re.DOTALL)]


with open('data.json','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(transcript ,f)
```